# How to Restrict controllers or routes for different type of users in API

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working on a project with laravel. in my project there's two type of users one of them are admins and other one is normal users.
btw project is only provides API and there's no blade views.

I give a token to any user or admin logins with the api. and application will identify user or admin by sending that token with an authorization header and I check if token is validate and the user type is admin then give access to the admin features for that client.
here's my code for this part:

```php
$admin = Auth::guard('admin-api')->user();
if ($admin) {
    // allow to use admin features
}
else {
    return response()->json(['error' => 'token is invalid'], 401);
}
```

I read something about applying Restrictions on a controller class in laravel and it was written there to add a constructor like this into controller class:

```php
  public function __construct() {
    $this->middleware('admin-api');
  }
```

and also there's something like that just for Restricting routes. [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30643810/restrict-route-access-to-non-admin-users)

but I just want to know is it necessary to add same constructor to my controller class while the project just provides API? or the way that I'm doing is correct?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it right.

I would prefer restricting the request via routes, so there is no need to add constructor on each new Controllers.

```
Route::middleware(['admin-api'])
    ->group(function () {
        Route::get('cart', 'Carts\CartController@retreive');
        Route::post('cart/coupon', 'Carts\CartCouponController@addCoupon');
        Route::delete('cart/coupon', 'Carts\CartCouponController@deleteCoupon');
        Route::delete('cart/flyer', 'Carts\CartController@deleteFlyer');
    });
```

This will apply the `admin-api` middleware on all the routes in the group and there is no need to add a constructor on `Carts\CartController` and `Carts\CartCouponController`, just to have middleware restriction.

Comment: hmmmm ... I think you misunderstood! I wanna know in API projects should I restrict routes or controllers with middleware? or it's just ok to check the token and see if that user is admin or not?(like first code box)

Comment: Sorry for the late response. As far as I know, it doesn't matter whether you are restricting it in the constructor or route. Laravel is a mature framework and security flaws are addressed quickly. When you are working with API projects, tokens will be all that you have to check the authenticity of the request. So to check if the user is admin or not, you definitely has to check the token and that too for each request. You can cache the token-user relation if you don't want to hit the database on each request.