# how can I restricted route for vendor who is not approved in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-authentication

I have 3 types of users Admin, Vendor, Customer in my laravel E-commerce.

Now I have to restrict routes for those vendors who are not approved by admin.
Can someone please tell me the process, please?

here are the two tables users and shops.

users have those attributes

```
id, name, password, email, phone
```

and shops have

```
shop_name, address, shop_phone, owner_id (this is a foreign key of users.id), is_approved(bool)
```

- users hasOne shop relation are given here.

Now I need to know How can I restrict all auth routes who are not approved means `is_approved==0` for shops.

Can Anyone please help me?

Comment: You can define your own middleware, and then assign it to those routes like auth. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30643915/6908226

Comment: Please include the routes as it is hard to grasp what you are trying to do without em. What will happen in the case where an user has two shops?

Comment: i want to add a middleware in construct. if it is possible that 
it it is vendor but user()->shops()->is_activated == 0 then it return to login page. not going to next. like handle() . Is it possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible, but it needs to use similar way again. Instead of this `$this->middleware('newMiddleware');` use this: `$this->middleware(function ($request, $next) { // ... });` See this section: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/controllers#controller-middleware

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a middleware:

```
php artisan make:middleware CheckIsApproved
```

A new middleware class will be created in `app/Http/Middleware/CheckIsApproved.php` fille.

Then in the`handle` method of the middle, you can do the check:

```
public function handle ($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (auth()->user()->shop->is_approved) {
        return $next($request);
    }

    return back()->with('error', 'Unauthorized');
}
```

(You may need to customize the condition in the`if` according to the relationship)

In the file `app/Http/Kernel.php`, register the middleware: search `$routeMiddleware` property and add:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    //...
    'isApproved' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckIsApproved::class,
];
```

Then, in your route definition, you can specify the middleware:

```
Route::get('/some-route', 'SomeRouteController@show')->middleware('isApproved');
```

---

Check the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/middleware) for more insight

Comment: @Iagbox: Not exactly. Here, the `shop` method on the `User` model is supposed to define a relationship between the `User` and the `Shop` models.

Comment: You are right. I mean `auth()->user()->shop->is_approved`. I've corrected the answer.

Comment: nice, just stopping the next question being some error about that that they can't resolve :) thank you for putting up an answer to their question btw, always appreciated

Comment: Thanks for your answer brother. It's work for me. Thanks a lot. :)